# SFINAE and number of parameters

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have a template class `C<T>` which I intend to instantiate with `T` as some other classes `A` and `B`. `C<T>` has a method `foo` whose signature I would like to depend on whether `T` was instantiated as `A` or `B`. For example, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    void message() {
        std::cout << "message with no args" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    void message(int x) {
        std::cout << "message with " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class C {
private:
    T internal;
public:
    C(T& x) {
        internal = x;
    }
    void call() {
        internal.message();
    }
    void call(int x) {
        internal.message(x);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    A a;
    B b;
    C<A> ca(a);
    C<B> cb(b);
    ca.call();
    cb.call(42);
//  ca.call(42);  ERROR HERE
    return 0;
}
```

This runs correctly. `ca.call(42)` would raise a compilation error because there is no method `A::message(int)`. However, if I for some reason introduce a method `A::message(int)` in `A`, the code may allow calling `ca.call(42)`, which I would like to prevent.

I know that SFINAE techniques would allow to declare a method `C::call(T::call_type x)` where `T::call_type` would be a typedef for each intended instantiation of `T`. However, this only allows me to change the type of the argument of `C::call`. I would like instead to make *the signature* (in particular, the number of parameters) of `C::call` on `T`. I would thus prevent `ca.call(42)` from being a valid call even if there is a method `A::message(int)` in `A`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all the ins and outs of SFINAE, but what do you think of this?

```
template <
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, A>::value>>
void call() {
    internal.message();
}
template <
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, B>::value>>
void call(int x) {
    internal.message(x);
}
```

You can use `== false` too

```
template <
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, B>::value == false>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with template specializations:

```
// Main template used by every other type T.
template<typename T>
class C; // or some other implementation.

// This gets used for T = A.
template<>
class C<A> {
private:
    A internal;
public:
    C(A& x) {
        internal = x;
    }
    void call() {
        internal.message();
    }
};

// This gets used for T = B.
template<>
class C<B> {
private:
    B internal;
public:
    C(B& x) {
        internal = x;
    }
    void call(int x) {
        internal.message(x);
    }
};
```

If you don't like that you need to duplicate some common code, then you can have a base class with all those common things and inherit from it in each specialization.